# Creating a 2d Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

How do you make a 2d grid? Next, how do you replace random elements in that grid with something else?

I tried:

```
def introgrid( ):
     anyrow = 0
     print(columnrow)
     grid = [symbol for r in range(column)]
     grid2 = (grid[0]+"  ")*15
     for i in range(row):
         print(grid2+str(anyrow))
         anyrow+=1

symbol= "."
columnn= 15
row= 12
rowcount = 0
columnrow = "0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14"
```

This produces a grid but it doesn't let you change elements of it randomly. HELP!

Comment: Take a look at pandas [DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I have seen grids represented as lists in lists. I.e. if you want to make the following grid:

```
A0 B0 C0
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
```

you would represent it like so (keeping in mind that arrays/lists in python are [zero-indexed](http://python-history.blogspot.ca/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html):

```
[[A0, B0, C0],
[A1, B1, C1],
[A2, B2, C2]]
```

There are of course multiple variations to this sort of thing. One example that springs to mind is that you could store each row as a separate numbered attribute of an object. Since you are using lists (arrays) in your example, I'm going to assume you're going for an list-base representation.

You have variables which I understand as follows: `column` is the number of columns on the grid's x-axis, and `row` in the number of rows on the columns y-axis. It's generally good practice to make your variable names as clear as possible, so I'm going to use `num_rows` and `num_cols` instead.

If you want to make a grid, first you instantiate your rows, then you add your columns to each row. You could use a list comprehension, but those are probably harder to read that for loops. Using for loops, you would make a grid like so:

```
SYMBOL = '.' # it is convention in python to name constants in ALL CAPS
grid = []

for x in range(num_rows):
    grid.append([])
    for y in range(num_cols):
        grid[x].append(SYMBOL)
```

To access a random element, just use python's built-in [random number generator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

```
from random import randint

row = randint(0,num_rows-1)
col = randint(0,num_cols-1)

value = 'whatever you want to put in the random cell'

grid[row][col] = value
```

Comment: if I wanted to add numbers at the end of a row, how would i do that? For example I want the first row to look like: ". . . . . . . . 1" and the second row to look like ". . . . . . . . 2" and so on

Comment: Do you want an extra row/column, or do you want to replace the last item of the grid?

If you want an extra "border" around the grid, you just need a number of the end of each row `for iter, row in enumerate(grid):
        row.append(iter+1)` your column numbers are just an extra row at the end of the list with all your numbers `grid.append([1 for x in range(num_rows-1)])`

Comment: i want an extra column

Answer (score 2):

To make a 2D array you could write

```
width = 10
height = 5
grid= [[0 for x in range(width)] for x in range(height)]
```

And to access items in the grid just enter `grid[x][x]` where x is your position

*Edit*

I find the other answers to complicated. This actually gives you a grid. It's just a matter of how you present the data.

To **print** a 2D array as a grid representation you only have to iterate through the array

```
for item in grid:
   row = ''
   for subitem in item:
       row += str(subitem) + ' '
   print row
```

And to **change** every value in the the array, you could do:

```
for index, item in enumerate(grid):
    for subindex, subitem in enumerate(item):
        grid[index][subindex] = random.randint(0, 10)
```

Comment: that doesnt give u a grid though

Comment: That produces a grid, and if you randomly want to change the values for random positions, add random function for rows and columns and change to random values with condition applied to your function

Answer (score 0):

You can use for instance the `.join()` method of the `string` class to join some random symbols at each row, and then print it instead of dots. The random symbols can be obtained with the function `random.choice(list)` that randomly returns element taken into `list`. Here is the application to your case, where my `list` is the available uppercase chars and digits. You can play with it to select different random symbols.

```
import string
import random

% Grid dimensions and column numbers 
cols = 15
rows = 12
column = ' '.join(str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(cols))

% Turn the basic symbol into a string
basic_symbol= '.'
grid = '  '.join(basic_symbol for i in range(cols))

% Display the grid
print(column)
for i in range(rows):
    randgrid = '  '.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(cols))
    print randgrid + ' ' + str(i).zfill(2)
```